# Transform and scale doesn't hides the overflowed images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of rows with images. These images are appearing as small images. but if you hover them they are scaled. While scaling the smaller images are overlapped. The smaller image below the hovered image doesn't hide while the smaller image above it is hidden.

I am not sure where am i making the error. The class I am using for scaling is,

```
        transition: all 0.6s;
        -ms-transform: scale(6.5, 6.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(6.5, 6.5);
        transform: scale(6.5, 6.5);
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2000 !important;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
An example of how it is behaving is at,

https://jsfiddle.net/adnanj/1Lruex8f/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to not having a position on the images, `z-index` will not work without `position: ...`, in your case you can use `position: relative`